# How can I interrupt Speak?

Tags: dynamic, sound

I want to use an event handler to stop speaking:

```
Speak[ExampleData[{"Text", "DonQuixoteISpanish"}]]
```

The only way I can stop this is by restarting mathematica!

Comment: Quit[] has no effect

Comment: Fascinating - and if you execute something like `Speak["test test test"]; Print["hi"]`, it executes the `Print` command before the first word is even spoken.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like everything is pushed to a queue that is then inaccessible. `Quit[]` won't have any effect because all of this is done by the FE (which is why you have to quit _Mathematica_ to make it stop). I wonder if there is some hidden/undocumented token that can be used with `FrontEndExecute`...

Comment: Have you tried `ShutUp[]`?

Comment: Reminds me of the render queue, it too is uninterruptable.

Comment: I entered `Do[Speak[i],{i,1,1000}]` and couldn't make it stop, so I ended up here. Would make for a "nice" practical joke on someone.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Running `Trace[Speak["Hello"]]` and `Names["*Speak*"]` revealed the following possibility:

```
MathLink`CallFrontEnd[CurrentlySpeakingPacket]
```

Using this with a text that is split into a list of shorter strings allows you to interrupt the audio at well-defined points, phrase breaks, say. Here is one way to do it:

```
Clear[interruptibleSpeak]; 
interruptibleSpeak[text_String] := Module[{phrases}, 
   phrases = StringSplit[
      StringReplace[text, (# -> # <> "\n") & /@ {".", ";", "!", "?"}], "\n"];
   Do[While[MathLink`CallFrontEnd[CurrentlySpeakingPacket], Pause[0.1]];
     Speak[phrases[[i]]], {i, Length@phrases}]
]
```

You can now interrupt the computer in the usual way (<kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>.</kbd> on Mac, <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>.</kbd> on PC):

```
interruptibleSpeak[ExampleData[{"Text", "DonQuixoteISpanish"}]]
```

Now, of course, you do not get asynchronous speaking, so subsequent evaluations have to wait for the last phrase to be queued to execute.

**Note** This solution was tested on version 8.04, and is reported not to work on version 7.

Comment: Oy, first class spelunking!

Comment: Nuts!  This doesn't work on version 7 and I have a session open I don't want to close out at the moment.  Mute for however long DonQuixoteISpanish is. :-p

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Is it a V7 issue or a Windows/Mac issue? (I'm running Mac OS X)

Comment: I don't know, I haven't fiddled with it again.  I don't think I've ever had a practical application for `Speak` so this is not a high priority, but I'll try to return to this later to see if it can be mended for v7.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard However, it is very useful. Try `Speak[Array["I should migrate to v8"&, 10]]`

Comment: @Verde :^) ....